# Math.round: round number by conditions

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to round a number by the next things:

number with unit digits between 5-10 will be rounded to the nearest 10*x:

`(for example: 5->10, 6->10, 27->30, 40->40, 56->60, etc)`.

number with unit digits between 1-4 will be rounded to 0:

`(for example: 4->0, 11->10, 12->10, 20->20, etc)`.

I want to write it bu `Math.Round` function.

Meantime, I did it without it:

```
Dim rest As Integer = r Mod 10
    ' round up
    If rest >= 5 Then
        r = r + (10 - rest)
    Else ' round down
        r = r - rest
End If
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple to do with Math.Round

```
Dim roundedDecade as Double, originalNumber as Double
:
roundedDecade = Math.Round(originalNumber / 10, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 10
```

If you want to force the use of integers, just use CDbl and CInt to force some conversions.

```
Dim roundedDecade as Integer, originalNumber as Integer
:
roundedDecade = CInt(Math.Round(CDbl(originalNumber) / 10, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 10)
```

Comment: 15 is rounded to 20 (and it's OK)

Comment: Did you use the version for Integers that I posted as an edit?  Integer 25 divided by integer 10 = integer 2, rounds to 2, which 10x will become 20. Integer 25 converted to Double 25 divided by double 10 becomes double 2.5, rounded becomes double 3, then 10x becomes 30.

Comment: I tried the both versions.. r = 25 -> CDbl(r) = 25.0 -> Math.Round(CDbl(r) / 10) = 2 -> CInt(Math.Round(CDbl(r) / 10) * 10) = 20.

Comment: Okay ... I see the problem ... VB's Math.Round is not typical ... normally a .5 fractional value ALWAYS rounds up, not down.  But VB's Math.Round by default rounds a .5 fractional value to the nearest EVEN integer.  so 1.5 rounds up to 2, which 2.5 rounds down to 2.  Jeeze, leave it to Microsoft to do everything possible to be non-compliant.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You can use a rounding mode in VB to get always-round-up mode.  I've altered the answer to accommodate this.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131274%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I think it works: CInt(Math.Round(4 / 10, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 10)

Comment: You can answer it to me and I will mark your answer.. thanksss!

Comment: I'm not sure why you think .5 _always_ rounds up.  This is not a VB thing nor is it non-compliant.  It complies with IEEE 754 standard which Math.Round and the floating point implementation in .Net uses.  I believe that Java and most other languages adhere to this standard as well so it's not just a Microsoft thing either.